# C# Append lists in a list

Tags: c#

i have a loop that fetch some countries in my DB and according to a condition i need to put some value in that array and then at the end have a final list with all values. **Note that i will need 3 checks** ( level 1, 2 and 3) inside the loop:

```
    var countries= db.Countries
        .Where(x => x.name.Contains(searchText))
        .OrderByDescending(o => o.id);

    foreach (var country in countries)
    {
        if(country.Cities.Count() == 1)
        {
            customList.Add(new CustomClass
            {
                countCities = 1,
                name = country.name,
                level = "low"
            });
        }
       else if (country.Cities.Count() == 2)
        {
            customList.Add(new CustomClass
            {
                countCities = 2,
                name = country.name
                 level = "medium"
            });
        }


        else if (country.Cities.Count() == 3)
        {
        customList.Add(new CustomClass
        {
            countCities = 3,
            name = country.name
             level = "high"
        });
      }
    }
```

at the end i want to have something like this :

```
   [ { name="Canada",  countCities = 1, level ="low"}, { name = "Australia",  countCities = 2, level ="medium"},  { name = "China",  countCities = 3, level ="high"} ]
```

In PHP i know how to do it, but with c# im stuck !

Comment: What type is `customArray`? Generally we use generic collections these days rather than arrays

Comment: it's a list :   List<CustomClass> customArray= new List<CustomClass>() ;      I created this class to have my json data formatted with the values declared in the CustomClass

Comment: Then why does your question mention arrays? And why did you name your class `customArray` if it's not an array?

Comment: what is missing in the code? it seems to already select the data. One thing that could be added is call `db.Countries.Include(x => x.Cities).Where(...)` to avoid multiple selects inside the loop.

Comment: What is wrong with your code / what are you trying to accomplish?  In your example, there is only a single item that is a collection `customArray` so where is the combining?

Comment: I  think you need to change your query to target cities (get count by country) and then a join to countries (to get country name).
once you have that you can iterate through your query result and add your customClass (county, citycount)  to your list

Comment: mason, i changed my title. Maybe now it's better.

Comment: DaniDev , I updated my question. I still need to do a check (3 checks) . See my updated question . Thanks

Comment: drneel, see my updated question

Answer (score 1):

```
customArray.AddRange( db.Countries
    .Where(x => x.name.Contains(searchText))
    .OrderByDescending(o => o.id)
    .Select(c => new CustomClass { name = c.name, countCities = c.Cities.Count() })
);
```

Where CustomClass has a simple getter that returns a 'level' label does what you want but with less code

```
public string level {
    get {
        return countCities <= 1 ? "low" : (countCities == 2 ? "medium" : "high");
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated my question. I still need to do a check (3 checks) . See my updates questions . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use generic lists, those can be easily expanded:

```
List<string> stringarray = new List<string>();

stringarray.Add("New entry");
```

Combine them like this:

```
List<List<string>> lls = new List<List<string>>();

lls.Add(stringarray);

// Don't forget to re-initialize the startingarray if you want to reuse it.
stringarray = new List<string>();
```

If you want, you can even create a custom class 'CustomClass' and list that:

```
List<CustomClass> lcc = new List<CustomClass>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would eliminate the "SearchText"

```
 customArray.AddRange(from con in db.Countries
                      join cit in db.Cities on con.id equals cit.id
                      orderby con.id
                      select new CustomClass { name= con.name, countCities= con.Cities.Count()  }
                      );
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it !

```
  for (var index = 0; index <= countries.Count()-1; index++)
             {    if ()...

   else if()...

 }
```

is the trick !

Dont vote down if you dont have the good answer and try to have your own question. Thanks

Comment: I am wondering what you ended up using for your query code. was any of the answers useful to you?